# Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles

Tags: biblatex

Suppose I've just made the switch to [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex). I have chosen one of the built-in styles (`numeric`, `alphabetic`, `authoryear`, `authortitle`, `verbose`) or of the custom styles available at CTAN, and I've figured out how to sort/compress citations. The bibliography and the in-text-citations look approximately like I want, but need to be tweaked. I've taken a look at the `biblatex` documentation for advice, but it is somewhat daunting. How do I get started? To add some focus, customization in the following areas would come in handy:

- Suppressing of specific BibTeX fields (e.g., `publisher`);
- Formatting of fields for specific entry types (e.g., titles of articles not inside quotation marks);
- Formatting of citation postnotes (i.e., getting rid of "p."/"pp.");
- Spacing and punctuation in the bibliography (e.g., commas instead of periods as unit separators);
- Order of first names and last names of authors/editors in the bibliography;
- Order of certain fields in the bibliography (e.g., swapping `location` and `publisher`);
- Language-specific terms (e.g., replacing "References" with "Works Cited").

Finally, assuming that I'll want to use my style adjustments in a multitude of documents: Where do I put the relevant macro stuff?

Answer (score 579, accepted):

I'll start with a few words of caution. First, while most of the following tips should also be applicable for custom CTAN styles, my focus is on the standard styles that ship with `biblatex`. Second, these guidelines are about easy-to-medium modifications; for the trickier stuff look at some of the other questions at TeX.sx (or ask your own one).

### Introduction

As newer versions of `biblatex` were released, customizations that formerly required redefining internal macros (or at least changing settings mid-document) have become package options settable in the preamble. Here's how to do some often-requested tweaks:

- `giveninits=true` will render all first and middle names as initials. (Introduced in v0.8, renamed in v3.3, is called `firstinits` in pre-3.3 versions)
- `isbn=false` will suppress any `isbn` fields included in your `.bib` file. (It works the same way for `url`, `doi` and `eprint`.) (Introduced in v0.9)
- `dashed=false` (available for the `authoryear`, `authortitle`, and `verbose` bibliography styles) will print recurring author/editor names instead of replacing them by a dash. (Introduced in v0.9)
- `maxbibnames=99` will print complete name lists for multi-author/editor works in the bibliography while truncating those lists for in-text citations. (Introduced in v1.1)

Now, where to put actual customization macros? As you don't want to create a full-fledged custom style, I recommend to use the configuration file `biblatex.cfg`. This file, if available, is read by `biblatex` immediately after a style has been loaded. The (empty) original is located at `/tex/latex/biblatex` in your TeX distribution directory; put a copy in the analogous location of your local TEXMF tree (and update your file database) and fill it with the redefinitions I'm (finally!) going to talk about.

*Addendum:* You may also specify preamble options (but not bibliography/citation styles or compatibility modules) via the configuration file. Put the following into `biblatex.cfg`:

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{<preamble options>}
```

### Suppressing of specific BibTeX fields

For `isbn` & friends, see the introduction. Generally, `biblatex` differentiates between name lists, literal lists, and other fields, and different macros have to be applied to suppress those field categories. Should you, e.g., want to remove the `translator`, `publisher`, and `pagetotal` fields from the bibliography, add the following to your local copy of `biblatex.cfg`:

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearname{translator}%
  \clearlist{publisher}%
  \clearfield{pagetotal}%
}
```

See sections 2.2.1 and 2.2.2 of the `biblatex` manual for a complete list of fields and the categories they belong to. To suppress specific fields for in-text-citations (e.g., when using the `verbose` style), use `\AtEveryCitekey` instead of `\AtEveryBibitem`.

### Formatting of fields (and of citation postnotes)

As a general rule, inspect the "Field Formats" section of the file `biblatex.def` (location: see above). With regard to the example given in your question, look for the following:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
```

This means that for `@article` (and a bunch of other entry types), the `title` field is put inside quotation marks. (`#1` stands for the value of the field, `\isdot` prevents double punctuation.) In your local `biblatex.cfg`, change the last part from `{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}` to `{#1\isdot}`, and you're set with regard to the bibliography. In case your "parent" style prints titles as part of in-text-citations, you'll have to modify the `citetitle` field in the same way.

For the formatting of citation postnotes, the same principles as above apply, so I'll just post the solution to your actual question. ;-)

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}% no postnote prefix in "normal" citation commands
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}% no postnote prefix in "multicite" commands
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}% no prefix for the `pages` field in the bibliography
```

### Bibliography – spacing and punctuation

Section 3.10.1 "Generic [Formatting] Commands and Hooks" of the manual provides the basics, the "Formatting Commands" section of `biblatex.def` contains the actual macros. With regard to your example question (How to replace unit-separator periods with commas?),

```
\newcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addperiod\space}
```

needs to be redefined (using `\renewcommand`!) as

```
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
```

### Bibliography – order of first names and last names

The standard styles shipped with `biblatex` use two different name formats for the bibliography: `default` (used by `numeric` and `alphabetic`) and `sortname` (used by `authoryear`, `authortitle`, and `verbose`). (In-text-citations are the domain of a third name format, `labelname`.) These name formats in turn utilize auxiliary macros such as

- `family-given/given-family`: lead author of multi-author works is printed as "last name – first name", follow-up authors are printed as "first name – last name";
- `family-given`: all authors are printed as "last name – first name";
- `given-family`: you guessed it.

To change the name format for, say, the `authortitle` bibliography style (by default `family-given/given-family`) to, say, `family-given`, apply the following:

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
```

These name formats were renamed in version 3.3, see [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864), before version 3.3 `family` was `last`, and `given` was `first` in the above. The old names continue to work, but generate warnings; the new names should be used.

### Bibliography – order of certain fields

Let's delve into the files `standard.bbx` and `<myparentstyle>.bbx`, both of them located in the `/bbx` subdirectory of your `biblatex` folder. As per your question, you want to swap the `location` and `publisher` fields. Suppose you encounter the following code snippet in `standard.bbx`:

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \printnames{author}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{location}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{year}%
  \finentry}
```

Copy-pasting this definition to your local copy of `biblatex.cfg` and swapping the respective code lines should be a piece of cake, right? Wrong! While the "bibliography driver" shown above is functional (the example is taken from section 4.2.3 of the manual), the actual drivers are much more complex. They regularly use macros to print specific name lists, literal lists, or fields, and the macro definitions of `standard.bbx` may be modified by `<myparentstyle>.bbx`. Assuming your parent style is `authortitle`, tracing the drivers and macros will bring forth the following definition:

```
\newbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}
```

Note the `\iflistundef` macro which will print either a comma or a colon, depending on whether the `publisher` list is defined. (The `\setunit*` macro will only print its argument if the last printing command did actually print anything.) A possible redefinition – and the answer to your question – would be

```
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}
```

By the way, redefining `publisher+location+date` will (and for the sake of consistency should) affect other entry types besides `@book`.

### Language-specific terms

To change these, you need to modify the "localization keys" listed in section 4.9.2 of the manual. With regard to your example question, the following code does the trick:

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  references = {Works Cited},
}
```

(Actually, a long and a short form is assigned to every localization key. However, with `biblatex.cfg` it is not possible to separately override these two expressions.)

### Afterword

TeX.sx features a lot of questions/answers about customizing `biblatex`, with the solutions spanning everything from cute and simple macro redefinitions to venturous hacking of `biblatex` internals. Some notable ones (no claim to be complete):

- [Suppress "In:" for articles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10682/suppress-in-biblatex) (by Herbert);
- [Put thin spaces between initials](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10203/biblatex-putting-thin-spaces-between-initials) (by Will Robertson) (obsolete with v1.3);
- [Remove the parentheses around the year for authoryear styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12254/how-to-remove-the-parentheses-around-the-year-in-biblatex-authoryear-style) (one answer by Alan Munn, another one inspired by egreg);
- [Reverse reference numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21401/biblatex-reverse-numbering-i-e-count-down) (by Audrey).

Finally, here's a real-world example of [tinkering with bibliography drivers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6743/biblatex-changing-the-order-of-entries).

Comment: Interesting thing is that you can also type `\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}` to apply corresponding sorting scheme to the `numeric` style.

Comment: You may add the hint that the modifications (e.g., to suppress certain fields) may also be included in the preamble of a document rather than the `biblatex.cfg` file. This would have the advantage that different styles can be used for different documents. Or is there a caveat that I'm missing?

Comment: @lockstep: please tell where is `\addperiod` macro defined? I've ran into  an error described in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230616/spurious-punctuation-in-xelatex-biblatex-cyrillic-or-greek but cannot even figure out where `\addperiod` is defined. It's strange but `.dtx` files for `biblatex` are not available on CTAN.

Comment: Maybe you could update this question in light of [`biblatex` 3.3 name formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864). I.e. `firstinits`->`giveninits`, `last-first`->`family-given`, `first-last`->`given-family`, `last-first/first-last`->`family-given/given-family`

Comment: @cryingshadow Thanks -- something like in the preamble is exactly what I need. ShareLaTeX appears to not understand the .cfg. However, the command seems not recognized in the preamble, so not sure what to try next.

Comment: Hey! Is there by any chance a similar way to customize Natbib styles?

Comment: How can I set the starting index of my citations using a `.bst` file?

Comment: what is a "local TEXMF tree"? Is it the folder in which my main.tex file is?

Comment: @Andrea See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69483/69445 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161001/69445. It is a folder with a certain structure that you need to register with your TeX distribution.